# Is there any way to omit the usage of int_to_string conversion function in this portscanner code

Tags: c, linux, unix, networking, network-programming

I tried to check the ports of a host from 0 to 1024 which are open or not. I used `getaddrinfo(const char*node, const char *service, const struct addrinfo *hints, struct addrinfo **res)` for looping the port numbers from 0 to 1024 (i.e the second parameter const char *service) by converting the `int` to string and then passing to `getaddrinfo()`. Is there any way to avoid using this conversion function?

```
char *convert_int_to_string(int num)
{
    int tmp;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    static char a[5] = {'0'};

    while (num > 0) {
        tmp = num % 10;
        a[i++] = tmp + '0';
        num = num / 10;
    }
    a[i] = '\0';
    for (j = 0; j < i / 2; j++) {
        tmp = a[j];
        a[j] = a[i - j - 1];
        a[i - j - 1] = tmp;
    }
    return a;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int status;
    char *node;
    char *port_no;
    int sock_fd;
    int i = 0;
    struct  addrinfo hints, *serviceinfo;

    if (argc != 2)
        error(1, errno, "Too many or few arguments\n");
    node = argv[1];
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    for (i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
        port_no = convert_int_to_string(i);
        status = getaddrinfo(node, port_no, &hints, &serviceinfo);
        if (status != 0) {
            error(1, errno, "error in getaddrinfo() function call\n");
        }
        sock_fd = socket(serviceinfo->ai_family, serviceinfo->ai_socktype, serviceinfo->ai_protocol);
        if (sock_fd == -1)
            error(1, errno, "error in socket() function call\n");
        status = connect(sock_fd, serviceinfo->ai_addr, serviceinfo->ai_addrlen);
        if (status != -1)
            printf("Port : %s is open\n", port_no);
        else
            printf("Port : %s is closed\n", port_no);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code runs and works as expected, maybe https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is better suited for your question.

Comment: Note: the code does not handle negative values, and it does not handle zero correctly.

Comment: AFAIK ports are unsigned numbers. You  might change youre data types accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to omit the usage of `int_to_string` conversion function in this portscanner code (?)

Yes use `snprintf()` to form `port_no`.

```
for (i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
   // port_no = convert_int_to_string(i);
   char port_no[40];
   snprintf(port_no, sizeof port_no, "%d", i);
   ...
```